# CSS Dropdown doesn't show but is positioned right

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/WTELW/4/

The following works fine on JSFiddle, but doesn't seem to work right in a browser (try copy pasting to a notepad).

I've tried setting the z-index for the layer, but that doen't seem to do it. I can see the layer positioned right, but still hidden.

Comment: Seems pretty good when I copy-paste your code. Maybe something wrong with your `<!DOCTYPE` declaration or else.

Comment: Works for me as well on both Firefox and WebKit browsers. Could you give some more details on how it doesn't look right, or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: I updated the original post with the actual document and stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown appears for me after removing `overflow: hidden` from the following:

```
#header {
    width: 1024px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

I think what's happening is that you have the `ul` (dropdown) inside the header. Since the contents of the `ul` extend outside the header `div`, and you have `overflow` set to `hidden`, you can no longer see the dropdown because it is being hidden.